# drawing plot using categorized vectors in R

Tags: r, plot

I have three vectors as below:

```
x<-c(1:10)
type.1<-c('B','C','D','B','C','C','B','B','D','B')
type.2<-c('C','D','D','B','B','D','B','C','D','C')
```

i want to make one plot of these vectors with vector x as x axis and other vectors in y, where each vector of data is represented as a straight line in which 'B' parts are shown as red 'C' parts are shown as blue and 'D' parts are shown as green. point of making the plot is comparing the distribution in different types so the order in which these lines are placed on top of each other in y axis is not important. 
im new to R and as i searched i think i should use ggplot but i could not find how this should be done.
i appreciate any hints.

```
|
|red.blue.green.red.blue.blue.red.red.green.red       #straight line with different colors
|
|blue.green.green.red.red.green.red.blue.green.red    #straight line with different colors
|
|_________________________________________________
 1   2     3    4   5    6   7    8   9     10
```

Comment: no in that question the user had two vectors and he wanted each of them in different colors, but here i mean how i can have each vector in several colors based on its categorization. you gave me a wrong minus, take it back please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will need to be reformatted to work with it the way you desire, and ggplot is a good choice:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# put data into a data frame for ggplot
dat <- data.frame(x=x, type.1=type.1, type.2=type.2)

# reshape the data from wide to long
dat_m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "x")

# start a ggplot, using the new "variable" column as the y values
# this will be what groups the values will automatically put new
# lines on top of each other
gg <- ggplot(dat_m, aes(x=x, y=variable, color=value))

# geom_segment draws line segments, and we just make the horizontal
# end the next x value and keep the vertical end the same
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(xend=x+1, yend=variable))

# these are the colors you wanted and this will map them to the factors
# in alpha order and names the legend "Data"
gg <- gg + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"), name="Data")

# saving the world from grayscale gggplot backgrounds
gg <- gg + theme_bw()

# pick good labels. i just zero them out here
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")

# show the plot
print(gg)
```

[image]

Check `?geom_segment` to see how to change the line width and other parameters.